# MultiIndex::insert(value_type&& x) destructs x even in case of the failure to insert

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

Is it by design or a bug?

Normally I'd expect an insert to not destruct moved-in argument in case it failed to insert.

https://godbolt.org/z/bofeMo8fd

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/indexed_by.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/tag.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>



class Base {
  public:
    virtual size_t GetId() const = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    size_t GetId() const { return 42; }
};


int main(int, char**) {
    // A tag to view elements in the order of insertion.
    struct Sequenced{};
    // A tag to view elements in the order sorted by type id.
    struct Ordered{};

    using ContainerType = boost::multi_index_container<
        // Elements are pointers to Base.
        std::unique_ptr<Base>,

        boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
            boost::multi_index::sequenced<boost::multi_index::tag<Sequenced>>,
            boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<
              boost::multi_index::tag<Ordered>,
              boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<Base, size_t,
                                                &Base::GetId>>>>;

    ContainerType container;

    // Insert first element.
    auto& ordered_view = container.get<Ordered>();
    auto new_element = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    auto insert_result = ordered_view.insert(std::move(new_element));
    if (!insert_result.second) return -1;

    // Try toInsert second element with the same key.
    auto new_element2 = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    auto insert_result2 = ordered_view.insert(std::move(new_element2));
    assert(!insert_result2.second);
    assert(new_element2->GetId() == 42);
}
```

Results in segmentation fault

Comment: I'd say it moves, it doesn't destruct. Any destructors are the consequence of the move (that you allow)

Comment: Well, the terminology could be different, like it "consumes" the value. I think the better terminology would be borrowing from std::set.insert() where it says "the function has no effect" if insertion did not take a place. The point however stays that MultiIndex:insert does have an effect and is not usable when collisions are expected, as it's unlikely the user is OK with loosing the input argument. There are obvious work-arounds, of course, like to do the lookup first to determine if insertion will succeed. But that's more cumbersome and less efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, [my answer](https://github.com/boostorg/multi_index/issues/71#issuecomment-1763426223) as posted on the related issue on Github.

> Boost.MultiIndex insertion does indeed *not* modify the `value_type&&`
> passed if insertion is unsuccessful. The problem with this line
>
> ```
> ordered_view.insert(std::move(new_element))
> ```
>
> is that insert expects a `std::unique_ptr<Base>&&` and you're passing
> a `std::unique_ptr<Derived>&&`: the way `std::unique_ptr`'s implicit
> construction works, this creates a temporary `std::unique_ptr<Base>&&`
> to which the value of `new_element` is transferred. All of this
> happens before Boost.MultiIndex is even called, and the net result is
> that `new_element` will become empty regardless of whether insertion is
> successful or not.
>
> One possible user-side workaround is to use something like this:
>
> ```
> template<typename Container, typename Derived>
> auto insert_unique_ptr(Container& c, std::unique_ptr<Derived>&& p)
> {
>   typename Container::value_type pb = std::move(p);
>   auto res = c.insert(std::move(pb));
>   p.reset(static_cast<Derived*>(pb.release()));
>   return res;
> }
> ```
>
> (https://godbolt.org/z/P5KW6q585)

Comment: Ah. I **knew** I was missing something. But as I didn't spot the conversion (I routinely skipped it in the debugger - lmao) I tried to read the implementation details of the insertion and didn't readily see evidence of preservation (in fact I thought I understood how the node type is being constructed anyways). Glad to see I was wrong.

Comment: Oh, wow. I completely missed this. Thank you for pointing it out and sorry for the noise!

Answer (score 0):

Note my answer missed [the real cause of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77297353/85371). I'll keep the potentially informative bits about standard library behavior that you seemed to get have overly optimistic expectations about as well, because that may still be helpful information to others.

> In fact, the corresponding standard library functions, like
> `map::emplace`/`map::insert` also may move even if insertion fails. I
> reckon this has to with trading off performance cost while maintaining
> strong exception safety guarantee (which [**is** documented](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/hash_indices.html))
>
> C++17 added new operations
> [`insert_or_assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign)
> and
> [`try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace)
> specifically to add that guarantee:
>
> > #### Notes
> >
> > Unlike `insert` or `emplace`, ***these functions do not move from
> > rvalue arguments if the insertion does not happen***, which makes it easy
> > to manipulate maps whose values are move-only types, such as
> > `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<foo>>`. In addition, `try_emplace`
> > treats the key and the arguments to the `mapped_type` separately, unlike
> > `emplace`, which requires the arguments to construct a `value_type` (that
> > is, a `std::pair`).